# Open python file using os.system and system arguments

Tags: python, pyqt4

I need to open a python file (from within python with linux using os.system) while also specifying two variables for the PYQT4 module.

Using the terminal I do the following

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum python filename.py
```

however when I use the same command with os.system I get an error

```
import os
os.system('open xvfb-xdg --auto-servernum python filename.py')
```

error:

```
 path/to/file/xvfb-xdg does not exist
```

Would anyone know the correct way to open the file using these arguments. I do not want to use the subprocess call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string on `os.system` should be the same you use on shell.

```
import os
os.system('xvfb-run --auto-servernum python filename.py')
```